# Am I obliged to select an answer to my question?

Tags: discussion

My question was regarding optimizing a technique 'A' for solving a problem, but I found out by someone's comment that the actual solution to the problem, my question is a part of which, involves not using the technique 'A' at all, but using some other technique.
The answers propose ways of optimizing the solution while using technique A (because I specifically asked for that), but a better solution to the problem which can be partly figured out by my question, would be not using A.

I'm a beginner so I can't accurately judge the answers. They're obviously good, because they have 5-10 upvotes. Should I, as a good user of StackOverflow select an answer? (it gives the answerer some rep or badges, probably) or just let it be?

Comment: You're under no obligation to accept any answers.

Comment: I normally ask the commentator to post it as answer and I'll accept that instead ( not sure is it a good practise :S )

Comment: @cjmling: Sure, that's ok. But few comments make good answers, so it normally needs much elaboration. Anyway, the OP could self-answer (with a nod to the commenter, probably), and accept after a (few?) days...

Comment: Questions on SO are about the longterm and other people searching for the same problem. You have the ability to select an answer, that answer then will be the first answer that people looking at the questions will see. If you see a very good answer that doesn't have many upvotes on your questions, you should consider selecting it, so  that future visitors will see it quickly. Otherwise it's totally ok not to accept an answer and just let voters decide whats going to be on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You're under no obligation to accept any answers.
>   [Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305745/am-i-obliged-to-select-an-answer-to-my-question?noredirect=1#comment245325_1038015)

However you are free (and [encouraged](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)) to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854521/where-and-how-to-bridge) [your](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404304/alloc-init-retain) [own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938821/pulse-animation-on-iphone) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875902/creating-a-c-array-of-cgpoints) explaining how you actually fixed the problem. If you used parts of the other answer(s), then it seems right to upvote them, but again there is no obligation.

Not only will it point out a potentially better solution to the community, but may gather you a few extra upvotes for your work!

If you quote parts of the other answers, don't forget to attribute them however.

---

You are also *able* to edit existing answers (though under 2k rep you'll have to have the edit approved) if you feel you can add to them. In this case I would usually ask the OPs permission out of politeness, but it isn't *required*.

[I did this recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32375114/916299). The answer helped, but wasn't quite complete, so I [added to it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32375114/revisions).